# RoR - Show model linked with a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my app I have `Users` and `Bands`. A `User` can create a `Band`, so in the database schema, the table `Band` has a foreign key `band_manager_id` referred to the `User` table.

The models are:

```
class Band < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :band_manager, class_name: "User"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bands, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In the band controller I have an index method:

```
def index
  @bands = current_user.bands
end
```

And in views/band/index

```
<ol>
    <% @bands.each do |b| %>
      <%= u.name %>
    <% end %>
<ol>
```

When I render the band/index page, Rails gives me this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: bands.user_id: SELECT "bands".* FROM "bands" WHERE "bands"."user_id" = ?
```

Why am I unable to look up bands that relate to a user?

Comment: Try changing `belongs_to :band_manager, class_name: "User"` to `belongs_to :band_manager, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "band_manager_id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly set `foreign_key` in `bands` association:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bands, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'band_manager_id'
end
```

Comment: thank you! this work for me, but I don't understand why I have to specify  the foreign key in the model with has_many associations?

Comment: By default Rails suggest a foreign key column from the model name. In your example it will be `user_id` because name of model is `User`.